# Is it reasonable to use 2 feature selection steps?

Tags: python, r, binary, classification

I'm building a model to identify a subset of features to classify an object belong which group. In detail, I have a dataset of 11 objects in which 5 belong to group A and 6 belong to group B, each object has been characterized with a mutation status of 19,000 genes and the values are binary, mutation or no-mutation. My aim is to identify a group of genes among those 19,000 genes so I can predict the object belongs to group A or B. For example, if the object has gene A, B, C mutation and D, E gene with no mutation, it belongs to group A, if not it belongs to group B.
Since I have a large number of features (19,000), I will need to perform feature selection. I'm thinking maybe I can remove features with low variance first as a primary step and then apply the recursive feature elimination with cross-validation to select optimal features. And also don't know yet which model I should use to do the classification, SVM or random forest.
Can you give me some advice? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in a first step you can delete all features with zero variance. Also, with 11 observations against the remaining features you will not be able to "find the truth" but maybe "find some good candidates". Whether you'll want to set a lower limit of the variance above zero depends on whether you have additional information or theory. If not, why not leave feature selection in the hands of the algorithm?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to do a primary filter first to reduce the work for the cross-validation since I have a large amount of features.

Comment: So it's about computational efficacy? Then it will depend on the details of your computation, the power of your computer and how many genes are going to be deleted depending von where you set the variance limit to deletion. You will probably have to try out what will work with your setup.